# How to show 0 when values don't exists?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to show 0 in values that don't exist

My information: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1b77/3

```
|people|
  |client|  |sex|  |city_id|         
    MATT      1      1
    STEVE     1      2

|cities|
   |id|   |name|
     1      EEUU
     2      BRASIL 
     3      ARGENTINA
     4      JAPAN
```

I'm trying to show a value when city = 3 and city =4 like this:

```
|people|
   |client|  |sex|  |city_id|         
     0          0      0
     0          0      0
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  * FROM people
WHERE sex =1 AND city_id IN(3,4)
```

Somebody can help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a city table, to tell you what cities to show data for. Then do an `OUTER JOIN` from that city table to your people table.

---

Based on the edit:

```
select coelesce(p.client, '0') client, coalesce(p.sex,0) sex, coalesce(p.city_id, 0) city_id
from cities c
left join people p on p.city_id = c.id
```

We still need a better understanding of what you want to do with the data that you do have. For example, I suspect you want to group by client of city and show a sum or count.

Comment: What columns do you want in the results for the data you do have?

Comment: Joel how can i do to search values with conditionals? like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65e01/1 . I want to show with conditionals but doesn't work. can you help me please?

Comment: Put the conditions for the person table as part of the join, rather than part of the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following query to get a result for all cities, with '0' for every value for a city without connected people.

```
SELECT  COALESCE(P.name, '0') AS client
        ,COALESCE(P.sex, '0') AS sex
        ,COALESCE(P.city, '0') AS city_id
FROM cities AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN people AS P ON P.city = C.id;
```

It might make more sense to show the city_id from your cities table though, like this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(P.name, '0') AS client
        ,COALESCE(P.sex, '0') AS sex
        ,C.id AS city_id
FROM cities AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN people AS P ON P.city = C.id;
```

Check out the [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65a152/11).

Comment: Hey @CarlitosMorales, I think you really need to think about what you are asking from your tables :-) If you use a filter like that in your query, everything that does not match the filter will not be returned - but you want it returned anyway? You could edit your question to explain what your purpose is with the query, maybe that clears things up.